# Anyone can help me to speed up this Google Sheet script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following script to refresh my Google Finance watchlist. I am not a programmer so that's why I copied this from somewhere and use it as long as it does the trick. It certainly works for me but it's kinda slow, and I hope someone can help me to optimize this script to make it better.

My understanding is, this script basically scan the whole table (7 columns and over 60 rows) to find out the no. of rows and column. It first empty the cells then fill the cell with original formula (which is GoogleFinance function for stock quote, something like that) to force the update for the whole table. I actually just need to trigger update for a specific column but I don't know how to do it (yep, not a programmer..). I tried to change the row = x and col = x to another values and it would help to reduce the scope of the update size of the table, and it help me abit only.

In order to make it update more frequently, I actually copy and paste those two for loops set 5 more times and use Utilities.sleep(10000); in between to make the script run 6 rounds a minute. So I can bypass the minimum 1 minute interval in Google Sheet setting. But yes, I know it's cause the script run even slower...

I hope someone can help me to speed this script up, really appreciate anyone can help! Thanks you!!

```
function forceRefreshSheetFormulas(sheetName) {
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('*Table Name*');
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var rowOffset = range.getRow();
    var colOffset = range.getColumn();

    // Change formulas then change them back to refresh it
    var originalFormulas = range.getFormulas();

    //Loop through each column and each row in the sheet
    //`row` and `col` are relative to the range, not the sheet
    for (row = 0; row < numRows ; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < numCols; col++){
    if (originalFormulas[row][col] != "") 
    range.getCell(row+rowOffset, col+colOffset).setFormula("");
    }
    };
    };
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    for (row = 0; row < numRows ; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < numCols; col++){
    if (originalFormulas[row][col] != "") {
    range.getCell(row+rowOffset, col+colOffset).setFormula(originalFormulas[row][col]);
    }
    };
    };
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

### pls enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.

```
function forceRefreshSheetFormulas(sheetName) {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('*Table Name*');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var rowOffset = range.getRow();
  var colOffset = range.getColumn();

  // Change formulas then change them back to refresh it
  var originalFormulas = range.getFormulas();

  //Loop through each column and each row in the sheet
  //`row` and `col` are relative to the range, not the sheet
  var ranges = []
  var blank = []
  var original = []
  for (row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      if (originalFormulas[row][col] != ""){
        ranges.push( `'*Table Name*'!${columnToLetter(col + colOffset)}${row + rowOffset}` )
        blank.push('')
        original.push(`${originalFormulas[row][col]}`)
      };
    }
  };
  updateGoogleSheet(ranges,blank)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  updateGoogleSheet(ranges,original)
};
function updateGoogleSheet(ranges,values) {
  var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
  var data = ranges.map((e, i) => ({ range: e, values: [[values[i]]] }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, spreadsheetId);
}
function columnToLetter(column) {
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0) {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

### reference

[batchupdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you so much for the new code! It is indeed speed up the whole thing.

Just one more question.. Since I would like to trigger the update every 10 seconds or about to bypass the 1 minute limitation of Google Sheet Time-Driven Trigger, is this a way to do it (e.g. I just copy and paste again for part of the code with Utilities.Sleep in between)? Or there is a more elegant way?

Add this at the end of your code,
  Utilities.sleep(10000);

then start from the first for loop again
  for (row = 1; row < numRows; row++) {

Comment: ```
function columnToLetter(column) {
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0) {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}

  Utilities.sleep(10000);

  for (row = 1; row < numRows; row++) {
    for (col = 5; col < numCols; col++) {
      if (originalFormulas[row][col] != ""){
        ranges.push( `'Current Yield'!${columnToLetter(col + colOffset)}${row + rowOffset}` )
        blank.push('')
        original.push(`${originalFormulas[row][col]}`)
      };
    }
  };

Comment: sorry for the mess up formatting... but yes, something like this

Comment: Really sorry Mike, I am a newbie here so I am not familiar how to make it look better. I thought ```````` would make the code part format better. seem not?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the right person to answer this question. Post a new topic or try to find a solution. Be careful not to face `429: Too many requests` even if there are no more limitations with googlefinance. But there are limits https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits. I hope you will receive more specific help.

Comment: if you want to refresh frequently, I guess we could store in properties so we don't have to search for formulas every time, just update ... if the actual speedup is not enough!